# Custom class in axis2 web service

Tags: java, eclipse, service, apache-axis, web

I try to create web service to Axis2.
I am use eclipse and the "Axis2 Service Archiver" to create aar file from java class.
My problem is that I have function that return custom class like:

```
public TestClass TestFunc(){
        return new TestClass();
    }
```

My question is how my client know what is TestClass?  , the TestClass don't show in the wsdl file.

Thanks For the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the operation TestFunc() appears in the WSDL - you should be able to see type corresponding to the TestClass in your WSDL. If you cant see, how does the WSDL show the return type of the TestFunc() in the WSDL..?

Thanks..

Comment: the TestFunc aappears in the WSDL, but the type TestClass is defind like this: <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://local/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="TestClass">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>