# Apache Tomcat - Axis2: Returning custom objects

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using Eclipse Mars, Apache Tomcat, Axis2, and Maven with its axis2-java2wsdl and axis2-aar plugins to create web service and its client.

The web service is simple at the moment: it has a list of Users (with User attributes:  nickname and Id) and allows someone to create, search, get and delete a user.

Everything seems to run OK on the server side. I implemented the service and tested that it works OK with SOAP UI (the functions operate as they should).

**Error:**

However, when I run the Java code for the client, I get the following error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: 
   Unexpected subelement {http://user.ws.soar}nickName
```

The problems occurs when I ***return a custom User object to the client***.

Here is the service.xml excerpt:

```
<operation name="getUser" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" namespace="http://user.ws.soar/xsd">
        <actionMapping>http://user.ws.soar/xsd/getUser</actionMapping>
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</operation>
```

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289787/how-to-return-custom-objects-in-apache-axis2-webservice) but this solution did not work for me.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue are appreciated.

Comment: The service works OK for functions that return list of  Double, Integer etc, object, but not for User objects.

Comment: I tried the Archive Generator Eclipse plugin and it seems that the services operate fine now. The question however, is still there. Could it be a problem of the Maven goals I specified?